# Is Rick and Morty satire/parody of Doc Brown and Marty McFly?

Tags: character, reference, back-to-the-future, rick-and-morty

As the title asks, is Rick and Morty satire/parody of Doc Brown and Marty McFly of the Back to the Future franchise? Or is it a generic play on the Mad Scientist and fish out of water cliché?

Answer (score 29):

Yes. This is discussed by the creator of Rick and Morty in the Back To The Future documentary that was released recently.

[See the Wikipedia article on Rick And Morty.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_and_Morty)

> The series has its origins in an animated parody of Back to the Future created by Roiland for film festival Channel 101.

Comment: Gratuitous content warning: [Doc and Mharti - Origins of "Rick and Morty"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bZqbm33onUE) –YouTube

Comment: I've never seen the show, but reading through that wiki, it seems to owe far more to [Peabody's Improbable History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mister_Peabody) from the old Rocky & Bullwinkle cartoons than to BttF.

Comment: It's true that it's based on BTTF (via "Doc and Mharti") - but I wouldn't describe it as a parody or satire - because it doesn't actually satirize any of BTTF.